# Installing PIL 1.1.6. ( error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 )

Tags: gcc, macos, python-imaging-library

I'm using Mac OS X Snow Leopard and i can not install PIL 1.1.6.
I have faced with:

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Should I change the version of gcc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried macports? it makes all of this super easy.

[install macports](http://www.macports.org/install.php), then run:

```
sudo port install py26-pil
```